# Is this a bug when comparing a nullable type with its underlying type using FluentAssertions?

Tags: c#, comparison, nunit, nullable, fluent-assertions

I was writing some unit tests for a utility library when I came across a test I would expect to fail that actually passed. The issue is related to comparing two `float` variables, versus comparing one `float?` and one `float` variable.

I'm using the latest versions of both NUnit (2.6.0.12051) and FluentAssertions (1.7.1), and below is a small code snipped illustrating the issue:

```cs
using FluentAssertions;
using FluentAssertions.Assertions;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace CommonUtilities.UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class FluentAssertionsFloatAssertionTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestFloatEquality()
        {
            float expected = 3.14f;
            float notExpected = 1.0f;
            float actual = 3.14f;

            actual.Should().BeApproximately(expected, 0.1f);
            actual.Should().BeApproximately(notExpected, 0.1f); // A: Correctly fails (Expected value 3,14 to approximate 1 +/- 0,1, but it differed by 2,14.)
            actual.Should().BeInRange(expected, expected);
            actual.Should().BeInRange(notExpected, notExpected); // B: Correctly fails (Expected value 3,14 to be between 1 and 1, but it was not.)
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestNullableFloatEquality()
        {
            float expected = 3.14f;
            float notExpected = 1.0f;
            float? actual = 3.14f;

            actual.Should().BeApproximately(expected, 0.1f);
            actual.Should().BeApproximately(notExpected, 0.1f); // C: Passes (I expected it to fail!)
            actual.Should().BeInRange(expected, expected);
            actual.Should().BeInRange(notExpected, notExpected); // D: Correctly fails (Expected value 3,14 to be between 1 and 1, but it was not.)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from my comments, in `TestFloatEquality()` both *A* and *B* fails correctly (just comment out the first failing test to get to the second one).

In `TestNullableFloatEquality()` however, *D* passes but *C* fails. I would have expected *C* to fail here as well. And just to have mentioned it, if I add assertions using NUnit:

```cs
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); // Passes
Assert.AreEqual(notExpected, actual); // Fails (Expected: 1.0f But was:  3.1400001f)
```

those pass and fail as expected.

So, to the question: Is this a bug in FluentAssertions, or am I missing something with respect to nullable comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a bug. I fixed this in both the 1.7.x release branch as well as in the trunk. Development on the new 2.0.0 is still ongoing, so we might decide to do a 1.7.2 release after all.

See http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/workitem/12199 for the exact status.

Comment: It's in the 2.0 beta version at http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/releases/view/82423